# Stencil Texture : How to align it exaclty to the camera region by code?

Tags: python, texturing, 3d-view, texture-painting, video

I'm doing texture mapping with tracked stencil video texture.
The probleme is that I cannot place the stencil exatly at the size of the camera vieport/region when looking from the camera.
I have tried to center it via python but is't  using the panel region(panel and menu bar included), not the caemra border. Also even if I painfully manage to align it with the camera, it goes of if I zoom, change panel size or switch workspace.
If the alignement could be automated, I could batch cam map the whole object/sequence.

Comment: This requires some Pythagorean math and probably some trigonometry as well AFAIK.